# How to sort records with particular field date mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I have a custom date in a particular field, I want data in sorting order, but not working, anyone have solution... here is my code

```
Releases.find({ company_id }).sort( { release_date: -1 } )
```

here is sample document....

```
         {
                "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "company_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "release_date": "12/11/2018"  // mm/dd/yyyy
                "datetime": "2018-12-12T14:54:41.609Z",
                "__v": 0,
            },
             {
                "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "company_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "release_date": "12/10/2018"    // mm/dd/yyyy
                "datetime": "2018-12-12T14:55:41.609Z",
                "__v": 0,
            },
            {
                "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "company_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "release_date": "12/12/2018"    // mm/dd/yyyy
                "datetime": "2018-12-12T14:56:41.609Z",
                "__v": 0,
            }
```

I want to sort according to user input date (release_date), any idea. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the user input date? Post the payload

Comment: Probably best to correct the format of release_date to something sortable like '2018-12-11'. You never want to store a date as a locale-specific string.

Comment: @JohnnyHK The issue is not with date I think. OP wants to sort with the date which the `user` passes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the field you are using are wrong . 
Both release_date and datetime have String as their value . Hence are not Dates .Hence String sorting rules apply . 
If you change your query to 
Releases.find({ company_id }).sort( { datetime: -1 } ) 
It Will work.

Comment: it will work, but I want sorting according to release_date, as this date can be different  i.e. 1 year old, 1 month old etc

Comment: How many records are in the collection , Its never a good idea to sort on string field which is stored as string. I would suggest to update/add a date field with value of Date(released_date) as its value.  
You can try  one thing . If the record is created on the the same time as the released date.  then sort on _id ( if it is ObjectId)